# Which database is good for automotive GPS tracker?

Tags: database, oracle-database, gps-tracking

we are developing a recording system for automotive gps trackers production of our company.
we log their data nearly 1 year and each gps node sends data to record each 5 seconds. each data contain about 50 bytes and we think nearly 5000 gps nodes we need to record in each server.
it means we have more than 20billion of records and nearly 1tbytes hard to save.
Can anyone help us which database is proper for such case?
We use mysql database now, but we think  it may cant handle after data increases.

Answer (score 1):

For such type of data and such size will be good to use kind of NoSQL key-value database. This will give you option for better scalability in sense of disk space, paralleling search operations.
One possible option is **MongoDB** with very powerful select type command and very good scalability.
Other option is **etcd** which support extreme write speed (1000 records/s per host).